# error generating new app with rails 4.0.0.rc1 on Linux Mint 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux-mint

I've installed rails 4.0.0.rc1 on Linux Mint v14 Nadia.

When I run

```
rails new something
```

It's giving me error (I'll put here only the last lines):

> create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
>            run  bundle install
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ui.rb:36:in `initialize': undefined method`[]' for # (NoMethodError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in `new'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in`initialize'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `new'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in`dispatch'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in`block in '
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in`'

Then I change directory to check dependencies:

```
cd something
bundle check
```

It says:

> Resolving dependencies...
>   Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
>   Install missing gems with `bundle install`.

Then I run:

> bundle install

And it's showing:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Installing rake (10.0.4) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.4) 
Using multi_json (1.7.3) 
Using atomic (1.1.9) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) 
Using builder (3.1.4)
```

... and so on that's taking more than an hour and still being run.

I thinks there's some strange things happening here.
Maybe my installation was not correct...

Comment: What version of ruby are you running?

Comment: Ruby version is 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I added:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

on to **.bashrc**.

The content of the .bash_profile:

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*